# NPM package as nested dependency of self

Tags: node.js, module, dependencies, npm

I have an NPM package (package A) that compiles itself with the last stable version of itself. It does this through an intermediary Grunt task (package B) that itself depends on package A. Thus, the dependency chain is:

Package A -> Package B (as `devDependency`) -> Package A (as `dependency`)

However, when Package A is installed through `npm install`, NPM won't install Package A as a dependency of Package B, presumedly by design - I assume it's trying to prevent circular dependencies, even though because Package B is only a `devDependency`, it won't be installed on the child Package A anyways.

What's the least-hacky/recommended way of installing the child Package A? My first solution was to just add an `postinstall` script that simply ran `cd node_modules/package-B && npm install package-A`, but this breaks because the CWD of `postinstall` isn't always the package's root directory.

Comment: Have you found any new ways of getting around this? As we've just been hit by the same issue - our testing library makes use of the libraries we are trying to test with our testing library. Works perfectly fine with manual installs as suggested but just really lame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about running making an js file for such a task?

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
spawn("npm", [ "install", "package-A" ], {
  cwd: process.cwd() + "/node_modules/package-B/",
  env: process.env
});
```

I'm not sure whether this will work, but maybe it inspire you to do more things with it ;)

Comment: Yep, this was the way to go. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Figured out a nice automated way of doing this:

1. Add this file to your project: [`cyclic.js`](https://github.com/bevry/base/blob/eafc464da10af7efc523c57ff19f840fa595e130/cyclic.js)
2. Add the following to your `package.json` files:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "preinstall": "node ./cyclic.js"
   }
   ```

With this solution, when you run `npm install` it will automatically force install the cyclic depencies for you without error.